# Yeoman generated angularjs ng-repeat not showing data from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, yeoman-generator-angular

My first foray into the MEAN world. I used `yo angular` to generate a bootstrapped angular application. Next I replaced the default content of the auto generated about.html with

```
<div ng-controller="AboutCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="thing in awesomeThings">
      {{ thing }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

An except of the about.js controller is:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name clientApp.controller:AboutCtrl
 * @description
 * # AboutCtrl
 * Controller of the clientApp
 */
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('AboutCtrl', function () {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

Related content from the index.html file are:

```
<body ng-app="clientApp">
.
.
.
<div class="container">
<div ng-view=""></div>
</div>
```

As I said, the only change I made to the entire application is to change the content of the about.html file.

I then use `grunt serve` to run the program which opens the application in a browser. When I visit the about page, there is nothing, blank. I have read a bit about angular but so far nothing I have read is giving me any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong.

When `yo angular` was doing its stuff, I noticed a red text that complained about `package.json` already existing, later on the process seemed to hang till I pressed I hit Enter, then it continued to overwrite the package.json file and proceeded to the end with the comment that everything completed without errors.

I sure will appreciate every help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('AboutCtrl', function () {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

implies that you have to use controllerAs syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="AboutCtrl as about">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="thing in about.awesomeThings">
      {{ thing }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The view looks correct, but in your controller, I would change "this" to "$scope" instead:

```
angular.module('clientApp')
 .controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
 ];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i believe that estus is correct about the controller as syntax.  here is some more info on that and your alternatives.

`this` implies that you are using the controller as syntax.  here is a the guide for the angular controller with examples of the two syntaxes https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller.  here is another helpful breakdown http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/.

If you don't want to use the controller as syntax, you should declare awesomeThings as a property of your controller's scope.  You will need to inject the scope variable to use it this way.  Here is how that would look.

```
angular.module('clientApp')
.controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.awesomeThings = [
     'HTML5 Boilerplate',
     'AngularJS',
     'Karma'
  ];
}]);
```